# How do I arrange Rails model items into columns when I only want certain items which meet a condition?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails model of locations that I have visited.  Each location has a region ID pertaining to one of the 5 regions I have visited.  So, for example, the location "Berlin Wall" would have region_id = "europe".

When navigating through the website, one first sees the 5 regions displayed (I also have a Region model).  If you click on a region, the next page shows all the locations associated with that region.

So, I need to call up all the locations, but ONLY if those locations' region_id is the same as the given region.  However, I'm not sure how to do this (using the .each method), while also splitting these locations into 2 columns.

Here is html and ruby code that I currently have.  Be warned, it is very messy, with a lot of repetition:

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
<% @locations.each_slice(2) do |location, locationb| %>
  <% if location.region_id.to_s.downcase == @region.name.downcase && locationb.region_id.to_s.downcase == @region.name.downcase %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <a href="/regions/<%=@region.name%>/<%=location.id%>">
          <h4 class="media-heading">|    <%=location.caption %> </h4>
          <img class="media-object" src="<%=location.image_url%>" alt="..." width = 400>
          </a>
          <p>|    <b>Date Visited:</b>   <%= location.date %>  |  <b>Near:</b> <%= location.nearest_area %></p>
          <a href="/regions/<%=@region.name%>/<%=location.id%>" class = "btn btn-primary">View</a>
          <a href="/<%=@region.name%>/<%=location.id%>/edit" class = "btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
          <a href="/<%=@region.name%>/destroy_warning/<%=location.id%>" class = "btn btn-danger">Destroy</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <a href="/regions/<%=@region.name%>/<%=locationb.id%>">
          <h4 class="media-heading">|    <%=locationb.caption %> </h4>
          <img class="media-object" src="<%=locationb.image_url%>" alt="..." width = 400>
          </a>
          <p>|    <b>Date Visited:</b>   <%= locationb.date %>  |  <b>Near:</b> <%= locationb.nearest_area %></p>
          <a href="/regions/<%=@region.name%>/<%=locationb.id%>" class = "btn btn-primary">View</a>
          <a href="/<%=@region.name%>/<%=locationb.id%>/edit" class = "btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
          <a href="/<%=@region.name%>/destroy_warning/<%=locationb.id%>" class = "btn btn-danger">Destroy</a>

        </div>
      </div>

    <%end%>
   <%end%>
  </div>
```

A lot of this code you can ignore - my problem lies on lines 1-6.  The problem is that with the `.each_slice` method,

- I have to repeat a lot of code for locationb, and
- It seems that the locations are only displayed if both locations in the slice (location and locationb) have the same region ID.

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How are you populating `@locations` array  from controller ? Try joins query with locations & regions table to get the data, so that you can avoid `if condition` checks in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

In essence, in your `Location` model you would add the following:

```
belongs_to :region
```

And in your `Region` model you would add the following:

```
has_many :locations
```

Then you could do something like:

```
@region = Region.find_by(region_id: 'europe')
@locations = @region.locations
```

The above will give you all the locations that fall under the 'europe' region.

One critical thing to remember about the above, you need to add a `region_id` in your locations db table for the above to work

Comment: ****my locations db:table already has a region_id. 

Right now it looks like the locations aren't being loaded to the browser, though it's not giving me any errors.  I feel like there's something missing from my Locations migrations file.  Would I not add something like:

    t.belongs_to :regions